# application is not responding while working on onBackpress method

Tags: android, android-layout

I was working with my android app project, and i wanted to improve the performance of my app with user interface, so i was working on `onbackpress` method to provide double click to exit. it worked fine for the first time. but when i logged out and tried to login to my app again the app is getting crashed. i don't know what to do
i am working on this project since 3 months. anyone please help me..
i do not have time to start the project again.i dont know whome to ask please help me anyone.
here is the image of logcat.

[image: logcat image]

```
public class DashBoard extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
private CardView notice, notes, updates, questionpapers, results;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private TextView txtWelcome;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    txtWelcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    notice = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.noticecardId);
    notes = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.notescardId);
    questionpapers = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.questioncardId);
    updates = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.updatescardId);
    results = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.resultscardId);
    // add click listeners to cards
    notice.setOnClickListener(this);
    notes.setOnClickListener(this);
    questionpapers.setOnClickListener(this);
    results.setOnClickListener(this);
    updates.setOnClickListener(this);
// initialize firebase auth
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
//check login status
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() == null){
  //  txtWelcome.setText(" welcome");
        startActivity(new Intent(DashBoard.this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
}
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
       super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dash_board, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    //here is the main place where we need to work on.
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {

        case R.id.nav_notice:
            Intent h = new Intent(DashBoard.this, NoticeActivity.class);
            startActivity(h);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_notes:
            Intent i = new Intent(DashBoard.this, NotesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_question_papers:
            Intent g = new Intent(DashBoard.this, QuestionPaperActivity.class);
            startActivity(g);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_update:
            Intent s = new Intent(DashBoard.this, UpdatesActivity.class);
            startActivity(s);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            Intent k = new Intent(DashBoard.this,LogoutActivity.class);
            startActivity(k);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.noticecardId:
            i = new Intent(this, NoticeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.notescardId:
            i = new Intent(this, NotesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.questioncardId:
            i = new Intent(this, QuestionPaperActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.updatescardId:
            i = new Intent(this, UpdatesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            break;
        /*case R.id.resultscardId:
            i = new Intent(this, ResultsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        default:
            break;*/
    }

}
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

}
```

and this is my **MainActivity.java** file

```
package com.example.madhu.management;



import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnLogin;
EditText input_email,input_password;
TextView btnSignup,btnForgotPass;
public static final int NO_NETWORK = 1;

RelativeLayout activity_main;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    //View
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_btn_login);
    input_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    input_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    btnSignup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_btn_signup);
    btnForgotPass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login_btn_forgot_password);
    activity_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnForgotPass.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Init Firebase Auth
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Check already session , if ok-> DashBoard
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DashBoard.class));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.login_btn_forgot_password)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForgotPassword.class));
        finish();
    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.login_btn_signup)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUp.class));
        finish();
    }
    else if(view.getId() == R.id.login_btn_login)
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(input_email.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(input_password.getText().toString())){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill Required fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else {
            loginUser(input_email.getText().toString(), input_password.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}

private void loginUser(String email, final String password) {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loging in please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to login...["+task.getException()+"]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        if(password.length() < 6)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password length must be over 6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//                                Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(activity_main,"Password length must be over 6",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
  //                              snackBar.show();
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DashBoard.class));
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

and the error is pointing to this line

```
 auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
```

AND THIS
    `loginUser(input_email.getText().toString(), input_password.getText().toString());`

Comment: `@SuppressWarning("statement with empty body")`

Comment: Where's the crash log?

Comment: i have provided the image link

Comment: The image is not helpful. You need to post a stack trace, which looks something like [this](http://westplain.sakuraweb.com/translate/Android%2520Studio/Debug%2520Your%2520App/img/android-monitor-logcat_2-2_2x.png)

Comment: no. the logcat is not generating any such stack trace.. i tried running the app several times i didnot find any such message.

Comment: let me post the whole logcat file for u.

Comment: your logcat is set to ```firebase```, set it to your application or ```no filters```, and type something like ```"exception"``` into the filter bar, then look around for your application. Alternatively start typing your package name and see what logging appears. ```No filters``` is my goto when I can't find a logcat something that just happened. 
I reckon your issue is you're having a NPE on the drawerlayout just cause you don't null check it

Comment: @ SaikCaskey i have edited my question with new logcat image.please have a look

Comment: We can't see the entire error message. The NullPointerException should tell you that something is null where it shouldn't be. It says attempt to invoke virtual method(x) on a null object reference. Is that method your method, or can you see where you're trying to call it? If you can't see where that method is being called, maybe one of your arguments to one of the function calls listed in the stack trace with a blue link isn't right.

Comment: that error message is pointing to line number 87 & 79, which i have highlited in the question at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, but the longest line, the one telling you the name of the method that was trying to be called on a null object, is cut off.

Comment: @rguessford here is the line u asd for `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zzb(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference`

Comment: thankyou guys for us help for my question, i appreciate that. i got my issue resolved. the problem was dependencies of  firebase i used. i used 9.8.0 version when i first created this app.now i tried to add firebase database and its version was 11.8.0 so i changed the version of previous also. so it was showing the error for that. now when i changed the version to 9.8.0 it is not showing any error and working fine. thank you guys once again for all.